# inserting multiple rows in database using SQL server database

Tags: java, jdbc, batch-processing

I am developing Struts 2 application using SQL server database. 
I have a form with 2 rows of data, when I am inserting data, the data is not inserted in the same line, example : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDTS4.png)

the result I want is this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6BBg.png)

this is how I enter it in my jsp  : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSOMy.png)

As you can see, you do not enter any null values

My class identity :

```
public class CoordenadasP {


String CordNort;
String CordSurr;

public CoordenadasP(String CordSurr, String CordNort ){


    this.CordNort=CordNort;
    this.CordSurr=CordSurr;
}


public CoordenadasP(){



}



public String getCordNort() {
    return CordNort;
}


public void setCordNort(String cordNort) {
    CordNort = cordNort;
}


public String getCordSurr() {
    return CordSurr;
}


public void setCordSurr(String cordSurr) {
    CordSurr = cordSurr;
}



}
```

my class Model:

```
public static  String addMoreDetails(List<CoordenadasP> cords) throws Exception
{  
    try
    {

        Connection con=Coneccion.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into Coordenadass (CodN,CodS) values(?,?);");

     for(CoordenadasP cord : cords) {
         ps.setString(1, cord.getCordNort());
         ps.setString(2, cord.getCordSurr());

         ps.addBatch();
    }
    int counts[] = ps.executeBatch();
    if ( counts.length == cords.size() )
        return "someMEssage";
    else
        return null; 
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
    return ex.toString();
   }
}
```

and my action :

```
public class ActionCoordenadass extends ActionSupport{


private ArrayList <CoordenadasP>  cords;



public ArrayList<CoordenadasP> getCords() {
    return cords;
}



public void setCords(ArrayList<CoordenadasP> cords) {
    this.cords = cords;
}



public String inserCord() throws Exception{
    ModelCoordenaP ad = new ModelCoordenaP();
    ModelCoordenaP.addMoreDetails(cords);

    return SUCCESS;

}
```

mi JSP :

```
</head>
    <body>
<s:form role="form" action="inserCord" method="POST">
               <table>
<tr>
    <td width="10%">Reg X:</td>
    <td width="15%" >Reg Y :</td>

</tr>
  <tr>
     <td  width="30%" ><input  type="text" name="details.CordNort" /></td>

    <td  width="30%" ><input  type="text" name="details.CordSurr"  /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td  width="30%"><input type="text" name="details.CordNort"  ></td>
  <td  width="30%"><input type="text" name="details.CordSurr"  ></td> 
  </tr>
<tr>
 <td  width="30%"><input type="text" name="details.CordNort"  ></td>
  <td  width="30%"><input type="text" name="details.CordSurr" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SAVE</button>
              </div> 
            </s:form>
     <s:form role="form" action="consulta" method="POST"> 
              <div class="box-footer">
                <button href="#" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">RETURN!</button>
              </div>
      </s:form>
```

I know I'm doing something wrong but I do not know

Comment: I suppose `null` values are never sent to your action. You better post your `.jsp` code and also your full action code (`cords` declaration and usage )

Comment: Is the code related to Struts2?

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly, update my question, 
I do not understand why line-by-line is not recorded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @DrGun Gun Welcome to SO,

information you provided is insufficient but my guess is the problem is with

```
for(CoordenadasP cord : cords) {
     ps.setString(1, cord.getCordNort());
     ps.setString(2, cord.getCordSurr());

     ps.addBatch();
}
```

Here in **for(CoordenadasP cord : cords) {** line.

The reason six row is inserted coz that loop is being executed six times, so first get data correctly in that object and you will be good to go.!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering

I just updated my question, I still do not get the desired result

Comment: Hi, it is still insufficient, clearly what you written as model is not model also controller is not clear. please try and debug the code, if not comfortable with that, just print how many objects you have before inserting also print inserted rowcount.